# Variable Index value mapping Dataweave

Tags: dataweave

Here is the input payload from where I have to map the following item

```
{
    "externalOrderLineRefs": [
        {
            "sourceSystem": "Shutterfly",
            "identifier": "SFLYOrderLine09876"
        }
    ],
    "externalQuoteLineRefs": [
        {
            "sourceSystem": "Salesforce",
            "identifier": "SFDCQuoteLine123"
        },
        {
            "sourceSystem": "Shutterfly",
            "identifier": "SFLYQuote123456"
        }
    ]
}
```

**The mapping condition:**
Quote    = externalQuoteLineRefs.identifier WHERE sourceSystem = "Shutterfly"

Answer (score 3):

Will this do the trick? Otherwise exact output would be very beneficial.

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
payload.externalQuoteLineRefs filter $.sourceSystem == "Shutterfly" map {
    quote: $.identifier
}
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "quote": "SFLYQuote123456"
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the input, although here is what worked for me as the above input json snippet was inside bigger json payload.

Comment: In the future, you should include the full payload and expected output in your question. Otherwise, we're all guessing at what you're trying to do. Also, your answer is almost identical to mine, which is probably why others are downvoting your answer.

Comment: Actually the problem of stackoverflow is there is a limit of information in terms of code and explanation that can be put up over here. So considering that I had given what also might have helped few others like to try out indexing and stuffs with dataweave. when they downvote it people should leave the reason as well so that one can correct it. Anyways thank you for your time :) and being humble :).

Comment: That's fair, and I agree, comments definitely help us all grow in knowledge. Have a wonderful rest of your day!